# Authors with different affiliations on one line in apa6

Tags: apa6, affiliation, authblk

When using this example:

```
\documentclass[man,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage{authblk}


    \title{TITLE}
    \shorttitle{SHORT TITLE}
    \author[1]{Author 1}
    \author[2]{Author 2}
    \author[1]{Author 3}
    \author[1]{Author 4}
    \affil[1]{University 1}
    \affil[2]{University 2}
    \date{}


\begin{document}
    \maketitle  
\end{document}
```

the word "Affiliation" is placed under University 2. I do not understand why this happens.

[image]

Comment: I found a workaround using the following code (the problem comes from the apa6 documentclass)

\makeatletter
 \@ifundefined{@affil}{%
 \def\@affil{\relax}{}}
\makeatother

But I still get warnings, this time about not being able to close the title environment.

Comment: Nice workaround, although it gave me a 'There's no line to end here' error at the \maketitle command. So I changed your workaround into: \@ifundefined{@affil}{\def\@affil{~}{}}. I get no errors or warnings (and the ~ sign is invisible).

Comment: I came a cross another problem when using the authblk package, which is that all indents were removed from my paper, and `\indent` no longer worked. I do not really understand why the authblk package is needed anyway, as you can simply type out the output authblk would yield in the `\author{}` command (e.g., `\author{Author1\textsuperscript{1} and Author2\textsuperscript{2}`. As for the affiliation, you can use `\affiliation{}` with a manual break to produce the same type of output (e.g., `\affiliation{\textsuperscript{1}Affiliation 1\\ \textsuperscript{2}Affiliation 2}`.

Answer (score 3):

```
\affiliation{~}
```

This code works for me.

Content for `\affiliation` is required by apa6. If it is blank, 'Affiliation' will be displayed as default content. This code uses invisible content `~` to replace the default content.

Comment: How about adding some explanation?

Comment: That worked for me too. No idea why it works.